# How to solve 'The parameter subscribed_fields is required ' curl -x post command error, for creating a facebook chatbot using node.js and heroku?

Tags: node.js, facebook, heroku, chatbot

Heroku worked successfully , facebook page and app was created, webhook setup. But to allow chatbot to send / receive messages , curl command -x POST was used on terminal prompt -  graph.api v3.2  , 
But throws an error stating It requires subscribed fields.

v3.2 is current, do I use some other version perhaps where sub fields are not required? I tried 2.6-2.11 till 3.2 . None of it works, throws undefined errors to sub field require errors.

curl -X POST "https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/me/subscribed_apps?access_token=(here I put my page token id)"

Expecting an output saying - Successful True

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`subscribed_fields` just is a required parameter, so you can not subscribe an app for updates from a page without specifying which fields you want updates for.

Documentation says type is an array of predefined keywords, so you should be able to subscribe to multiple fields in one request using `subscribed_fields={field1,field2,...}`

Comment: @AbdusSalam one or more of the fields listed in the documentation, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/reference/page/